# What are the differences between Hokkaido dialect and Tokyo dialect

Tags: spoken-language

I'm traveling to Sapporo in a week. I've already been learning Japanese for two years and can understand quite a bit of Japanese. Is there anything I should know about the dialect in Hokkaido? I won't be living in Sapporo, I'll only be touring for a few weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, in an urban setting, Osaka is the only place where many young speakers still speak with an accent different from that of Tokyo. Unless you need to communicate with elderly people in a very rural area of Hokkaido, you can assume that you don't need any special preparation. Wikipedia of course has a [long article about Hokkaido dialect](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8C%97%E6%B5%B7%E9%81%93%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80), but even if you read it before you go, there's a good chance you won't find it particularly useful.

As for individual vocabulary, words such as しばれる and したっけ are recognized as typical of the Hokkaido dialect even by people outside of Hokkaido. It might be interesting to read an article or two about such words before you go, but personally, I've never heard these words in actual conversation in my entire life.